# How do you update GoogleSign-In to work with the new Firebase Console and APIs?

Tags: ios, firebase, facebook-login, google-signin, firebase-authentication

So, I had everything working as of yesterday. Then I logged into my Firebase dashboard and there was a banner that suggested I try out the new Firebase console. "SURE! That sounds great" I thought.

Eight hours later, I cannot get Google Sign-In to work. Here is my GIDSignInDelegate method, which fires correctly and everything.

```
  func signIn(signIn: GIDSignIn!,
            didSignInForUser user: GIDGoogleUser!,
            withError error: NSError!) {
            if (error == nil) {
                    let authentication = user.authentication
                    let credential = FIRGoogleAuthProvider.credentialWithIDToken(authentication.idToken,
                                                                                 accessToken: authentication.accessToken)

                    FIRAuth.auth()?.signInWithCredential(credential, completion: nil)
            } else {
                    // Don't assert this error it is commonly returned as nil
                    print("\(error.localizedDescription)")
            }
    }
```

The problem seems to be that this doesnt create an event for

```
 FIRAuth.auth()!.addAuthStateDidChangeListener
```

which is in my app delegate.

When logging in with the Facebook API, it does fire the auth state change listener.

I have also tried with a completion block, the user is a `GIDGoogleUser` instead of an `FIRUser` which seems kinda weird, but I have no proof it would be a problem. Also, the error is nil. so it looks like the signInWithCredential is working, but the auth state change listener isnt firing.

The only thing I can think of is that there is a problem with the google sign-in part of the system as the new `GoogleService-Info.plist` I had to download from the Firebase Console has a different app ID than I had in my previous `GoogleService-Info.plist`. I tried replacing the new app id with my old one which didn't work at all. I then tried removing any reference to the old app id assuming that the new one integrates google sign in automatically. Still no luck.

Anyone had success updating?

Comment: Similar problem here. In my case FIRAuth.auth()?.signInWithCredential fails with code 17999 internal error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What fixed this for me is to create a new Firebase Project.

Go to https://console.firebase.google.com and choose CREATE NEW PROJECT. I tried everything I could think of in my old (upgraded) project and I just couldn't make it work. Also adding a new iOS app inside the old project wasn't enough.

I understand this is a bad option for a production app but as I'm still in the development phase wasn't a big deal for me.

Comment: I'll try this when I get into the office. It was actually the only thought I had left. Ill post back if it solves the problem. :(

Comment: Unfortunately this is the solution. Had to create a whole new project in firebase and migrate everything over. Everything worked perfectly after, just like before I did any of this. Not sure how people with apps in production are going to handle this...

Comment: That's exactly what I saw as well. I hope we get an official answer from Firebase team.

Answer (score 3):

I added "import FirebaseAuth" and it worked! I know the Firebase documentation didn't say to add this, but I decided to give it a try anyways.

Comment: This didn't fix it for me. Still getting an NSError on signInWithCredential completion with localizedDescription "An internal error has occurred, print and inspect the error details for more information." Error code is 17999 that means Internal Error.

Comment: Worked for me :/ I know it isn't pretty and it's not what the docs say but what can you do? Also, for what it's worth I'm using the actual downloaded SDK, not cocoapods

Answer (score 3):

You need to add "Web SDK Configuration". You still need to enter it even though you may only have iOS app!

1. Go to your "Auth" tab in the new Firebase console.
2. Click on "Google" under "sign in providers"
3. Hover over "Web SDK configuration (optional)", it will bring up the popover saying "Reuse a web client ID from an existing Google project. You can find your web client ID for existing projects by selecting your project and OAuth 2.0 entry on the Google API Console."
4. Hit that link saying "Google API Console".
5. Check under section "OAuth 2.0 client IDs". You need to click on the link "Web client (auto created by Google Service".
6. Copy/Paste your "Client ID" and "Client Secret" into your Firebase console under section "Web SDK Configuration (optional)"

Funny thing that you need to do this even though you may have only iOS app.

Re-Run your xCode project.