# Firebase Google signing shows the blank safari page with Website name url

Tags: ios, objective-c, firebase, firebase-authentication, google-signin

I am integrating Firebase with Google signing. It is working fine with my dummy project but in my project it shows the blank safari page with "Website name" when clicking GIDSignInButton.

[image: This is screen shot of safari page]

I think there is some project setting that is affecting my Firebase Google signing code.

Please suggest.

Comment: check with these steps in this ans http://stackoverflow.com/a/37487208/4831524

Comment: Checked with above steps but problem still appear.

Answer (score 0):

I found the reason of this problem.
I am using the AMSlideMenu library for side panel in my project that effect on safari. It's strange but after removing the side panel all work fine.

Answer (score 0):

The cause of my issue was the `[UIApplication sharedApplication].keyWindow` being `nil` when presenting the Google Signing view controller.

I created the method which retrieves and reassigns the `keyWindow` to both present the window and for the Google Signing SDK to continue working.

```
- (void) signIn:(GIDSignIn *)signIn presentViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController
{
    UIViewController *topViewController = [WindowUtils GetTopMostController];
    [topViewController presentViewController:viewController animated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

WindowUtils.m

```
+ (UIViewController*) GetTopMostController
{
    UIViewController *topController = [UIApplication sharedApplication].keyWindow.rootViewController;
    if(topController == nil)
    {
        UIWindow *keyWindow = [[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate] window];
        //reassign the keywindow
        [keyWindow makeKeyAndVisible];
        topController = keyWindow.rootViewController;
    }

    return topController;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Restarting phone seems to work for me.